# Variable is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am hitting an api and saving response in a variable but the variable in which i am storing is showing undefined by debugger.

```
        try {
      let response = await fetch(
       "http://test.kelltontech.net/eventengine/getmyevents?hash=****&timestamp=****&id=****",
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        }
      );
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      this.agendaDetails = await responseJson;
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
```

Here responseJson has data but not storing in agenda detail that is declared outside the main class like this **agendaDetails={}**

Comment: Have you tried changing the let for var ?  let has limited scope.

Comment: but i am not using let out side its scope

Comment: still same even after using var

Comment: Did you change both instances?

Comment: actually i am having problem in accessing the variable that is defined outside the class

Comment: I think the issue is going to be related to asynchronous access, isn't there a callback you can use when the response is received then you can do away with the await operations.

Comment: I think `this` is referring to some other instance. create a variable  before fetch & assigned `this`. then access `agendaDetails` using new variable like new_variable.agendaDetails.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, and perhaps a better long term solution; instead of using fetch and wrapping it in a promise and making a tweak to return json. Use axios. It has promise support as standard and returns and expects json output.

```
let result = {};

axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  result = response.data;
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Here is the link [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Answer (score 0):

you should use fetch with .then() to get response in json then assign that response to the variable just like below

```
fetch(URL.apiUrlUploadImages, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "front_image": this.frontImageData
                })
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseData) => {
                     var result = responseData});
```